# PS2 Keyboard Works In XP But Not In BIOS

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard, bios

I have a Dell Dimension 8400. I am trying to add a new SATA drive for addition disk space. When I enter the BIOS (F2 from the keyboard), two things happen. First, the monitor says it cannot display. I turn the monitor off and back on, and I can see the BIOS screen. Second, and most importantly, the keyboard does not work. This is the same keyboard I'm typing on right now. The Num Lock light is solid green, but the keyboard does not respond. I have tried another keyboard with no success.

Any thoughts on how to get the keyboard to work in the BIOS so I can get the new drive installed or any other approaches?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried a USB keyboard?

Answer (score 2):

I will recommend to [clear the CMOS](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/tp/clearcmos.htm).
Clearing the CMOS will restore the BIOS to the factory settings.